# Unknown error with self-defined function for approximation of an integral

Tags: python, numpy, sum, calculus

I've defined the following function as a method of approximating an integral using Boole's Rule:

```
def integrate_boole(f,l,r,N):
    h=((r-l)/N)
    xN = np.linspace(l,r,N+1)
    fN = f(xN)
    return ((2*h)/45)*(7*fN[0]+32*(np.sum(fN[1:-2:2]))+12*(np.sum(fN[2:-3:4]))+14*(np.sum(fN[4:-5]))+7*fN[-1])
```

I used the function to get the value of the integral for `sin(x)dx` between 0 and pi (where N=8) and assigned it to a variable `sine_int`.

The answer given was 1.3938101893248442

After doing the original equation (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_rule)) out by hand I realised this answer was quite inaccurate.

The sums of fN are giving incorrect values, but I'm not sure why. For example, `np.sum(fN[4:-5])` is going to 0.

Is there a better way of coding the sums involved, or is there an error in my parameters that's causing the calculations to be inaccurate?

Thanks in advance.

*EDIT*

I should have made it clearer that this is supposed to be a composite version of the rule, i.e. approximating over N points where N is divisible by 4. So the typical 5 points with 4 intervals isn't going to cut it here, unfortunately. I would copy the equation I'm using into here, but I don't have an image of it and LaTex isn't an option. It should/might be clear from the code I have after `return`.

Comment: That's a lot of parenthesis! `return 14*h/45*fN[0] + 32*np.sum(fN[1:-2:2]) + 12*np.sum(fN[2:-3:4]) + 14*np.sum(fN[4:-5]) + 7*fN[-1]` feels better no?

Comment: Not sure if this is it, but I think `32 * (np.sum(fN[1:-2:2]))` should be `32 * (np.sum(fN[1:-1:2]))` and `12 * (np.sum(fN[2:-3:4]))` should be `12 * (np.sum(fN[2:-2:4]))` (the last index is not included, so I think you are missing a couple of numbers there)... And well of course I assume `N` is a multiple of 4.

Comment: I still can't figure out why `np.sum(fN[4:-5])` goes to 0 for N=8. Is this always the result when you try to sum the same value with itself?

Comment: @rory_c Yes, since in that case `4` and `-5` represent the same index, the slice is empty (it is the same as if you did `fn[4:4]`), so the sum is 0. If you want to actually include that element you need to go one index further. So yes, I think I missed that one too and it should be `fn[4:-4]`, so the last begin/end is also included.

Comment: Yup it just worked for [4:-4], thanks

Answer (score 1):

From a quick inspection looks like the term multiplying f(x_4) should be 32, not 14:

```
def integrate_boole(f,l,r,N):
    h=((r-l)/N)
    xN = np.linspace(l,r,N+1)
    fN = f(xN)
    return ((2*h)/45)*(7*fN[0]+32*(np.sum(fN[1:-2:2]))+
                       12*(np.sum(fN[2:-3:4]))+32*(np.sum(fN[4:-5]))+7*fN[-1])
```

Comment: `fN[4:-5]` are the beginning and end of each integration segment and they are multiplied by 14 because the first and last point of each segment is integrated by 7 (so 7 for being the end of one segment plus 7 for being the beginning of the next segment).

Comment: Changing the coefficient makes no difference anyway as the sum within the brackets is zero. I'm trying to figure out why. (For this version of Boole's rule, 14 is actually correct as far as I know)

Answer (score 1):

First, one of your coefficients was wrong as pointed out by @nixon. Then, I think you do not really understand how the Boole's rule works - It approximates the integral of a function only using 5 points of the function. Hence, the terms like `np.sum(fN[1:-2:2])` makes no sense. You only need five points, which you can obtain with  `xN = np.linspace(l,r,5)`. Your `h` is simply the distance between 2 of the contiguos points `h = xN[1] - xN[0]`. And then, easy peasy:

```
import numpy as np 

def integrate_boole(f,l,r):
    xN = np.linspace(l,r,5)
    h = xN[1] - xN[0]
    fN = f(xN)
    return ((2*h)/45)*(7*fN[0]+32*fN[1]+12*fN[2]+32*fN[3]+7*fN[4])

def f(x):
  return np.sin(x)

I = integrate_boole(f, 0, np.pi)
print(I) # Outputs 1.99857...
```

Comment: It is a composite Boole's rule, so it is integrating using `N + 1` points where `N` is a multiple of 4.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I am looking for. As @jdehesa said, this is a variation on the typical Boole's rule. So, yes, I do understand how it works, just not how to code it up in this particular context. My main problem appears to be the sums within the brackets, as they are not accurate with the parameters provided. I'm not sure why.

Comment: oh sorry, misunderstood what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're hoping your code does w.r.t. Boole's rule. Why are you summing over samples of the function (i.e. `np.sum(fN[2:-3:4])`)? I think your `N` parameter is also not well defined and I'm not sure what it's supposed to represent. Maybe you're using another rule I'm not familiar with: I'll let you decide.

Regardless, here's an implementation of Boole's rule as Wikipedia defines it. Variables map to the Wikipedia version you linked:

```
def integ_boole(func, left, right):
    h = (right - left) / 4
    x1 = left
    x2 = left + h
    x3 = left + 2*h
    x4 = left + 3*h
    x5 = right # or left + 4h

    result = (2*h / 45) * (7*func(x1) + 32*func(x2) + 12*func(x3) + 32*func(x4) + 7*func(x5))
    return result
```

then, to test:

```
import numpy as np
print(integ_boole(np.sin, 0, np.pi))
```

outputs `1.9985707318238357`, which is extremely close to the correct answer of `2`.

HTH.

Comment: It is a composite Boole's rule, it is taking all the values multiplied by 32, 12 and 14 together (plus the first and last values multiplied by 7).